# I got issue with ember application after cloning disk

Tags: ember.js

I began to learn ember and did working app. It was working well. Then I had to change my hard disk to ssd by cloning my old disk/ After cloning i restore my ember app from bup and tried to start it. And got error.

```
C:\inetpub\tracker> npm start

> tracker@0.0.0 start C:\inetpub\tracker
> ember serve

The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined


Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Local\Temp/error.dump.90e842d8b8af33fd44bc24b48197a6bd.log
An error occurred in the constructor for ember-data at C:\inetpub\tracker\node_modules\ember-data

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tracker@0.0.0 start: `ember serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tracker@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-04T17_45_40_052Z-debug.log

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~prestart: tracker@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: tracker@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\inetpub\tracker\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\watchman;C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\tnfoms\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\tnfoms\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd
9 verbose lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\inetpub\tracker
10 silly lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ember serve' ]
11 silly lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tracker@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: tracker@0.0.0 start: `ember serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid tracker@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\inetpub\tracker
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error tracker@0.0.0 start: `ember serve`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the tracker@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I tried to reinstall node, ember but unsuccessfully

Comment: Delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Sometimes npm just gets borked and you have to blow it away and start fresh